# Htaccess - How can i make this redirect a 301 instead of 302?

Tags: url-rewrite, redirect, htaccess, .htaccess, 301-redirect

My website redirects everything from http to https but 1 of the redirects is a none cacheable 302 redirect according to a few seo checkers i use.

How can i get the following code to be a 301 redirect instead of a 302?

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^lincoln-printing-services\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.lincoln-printing-services\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try appending `[R=301]` to your `RewriteRule` entries. If you have existing parameters (like `[L]`), comma-separate them: `[R=301,L]`.

Answer (score 1):

The following changed the 302 to a 301 between http://www and https://www

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```